# why do instance variables decide the state of an object while local variables do not

Tags: java

*I am a beginner.  Local variables are also a part of the object but still they don't decide the state of the object.  Any explanation?*

Comment: because they are ... local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that leads to the misunderstanding is the *incorrect assertion* that "Local variables are also a part of the object". (This facts provided for the argument/question is incorrect; if this was true, the argument/question would be valid.)

However, **Local Variables are *NOT* part of the Object**. Local variables exist only within the local (eg. method, loop) scope. When the method/loop scope terminates the local variables simply cease to exist.

(Inside the method bytecode, variables 'exist' only insofar as they are instructions for the JVM. However, the form in which they exist does not resemble Java source and this 'existence' should not be confused with "being part of an object". This method-level bytecode is not an object definition.)

That is, local variable *only exists* within a single method call. Calling the same method again, recursively or not, will create a *different, unrelated* local variable. Since each method scope is distinct, local variables *cannot* maintain state that crosses method boundaries.

Consider this:

```
int m (int x) {     // x is a local (parameter) variable
   int a;           // a is a local variable as well
   a = x;
   if (x < 10) {
     m(x + 1);
   }
   return a;
}

// If local variables DO maintain state in the object, and therefor
// across methods calls, this would print 10 as the "last"
// `a = x` line executed is the innermost call, when x = 10.
// (Spoiler: it doesn't print 10..)
System.out.println("A: " + m(7));

// Exercise: modify the above such that `a` is a *member variable*
// aka a *field*. How does the result change?
```

[Closures are a slight digression, but that's simulated magic.]